# Hubbard & Hubbard: "Uniqueness" of the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm using *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms, 5th Ed.* by Hubbard and Hubbard. On page 129, they have the definition of the derivative of $\mathbf f$ at $\mathbf a$ in the direction $\mathbf v$ as
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf f(\mathbf a + h \mathbf v) - \mathbf f(\mathbf a)}{h} . $$
**Proposition 1.7.14** says we can calculate such a directional derivative with the formula $[\mathbf D \mathbf f(\mathbf a)] \mathbf v$, where $[\mathbf D \mathbf f(\mathbf a)]$ is the derivative of $\mathbf f$ at $\mathbf a$. I am well acquainted with this formula and understand it intuitively, but I am unconvinced by their proof of this proposition:
[image]
I am not sure why, in equation 1.7.41, we can't just use arbitrary $\color{red}{\mathbf w}$ instead of the fixed $\mathbf v$ for $[\mathbf D \mathbf f(\mathbf a)] h \color{red}{\mathbf w}$, which would lead to equation 1.7.42 being
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf f(\mathbf a + h \mathbf v) - \mathbf f(\mathbf a)}{h}
    - [\mathbf D \mathbf f(\mathbf a)] \color{red}{\mathbf w} = \mathbf 0 , $$
which makes no sense. I suspect that when we use arbitrary $\color{red}{\mathbf w} \neq \mathbf v$, that
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf r (h \mathbf v)}{h \lvert \mathbf v \rvert} $$
is not necessarily 0, but it's not clear to me why.

---

P.S. I think a constructive proof of the directional derivative would be much more enlightening than this style of proof, even if it is less "elegant".

Comment: this $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathbf f(\mathbf a + h \mathbf v) - \mathbf f(\mathbf a)}{h}
    - [\mathbf D \mathbf f(\mathbf a)] \color{red}{\mathbf w} = \mathbf 0 $ doesn't follow from all the previous discussion. If you change $\vec{\bf v}$ by $\vec{\bf w}$ you must change it in all instances, and not someones. That is: if you have that $\vec {\bf h}=h\vec{\bf v}$ then $\vec {\bf h}\neq h\vec{\bf w}$ when $\vec{\bf v}\neq \vec{\bf w}$ and $h\neq 0$. In summary: what you are asking is equivalent to ask "why, in the identity $2+2=4$ we can't change the first $2$ by a three and get $3+2=4$?

Comment: @Masacroso On the first line of the proof they say $\mathbf r(\mathbf h)$ is *defined* as the difference between $\mathbf f(\mathbf a + \mathbf h) - \mathbf f(\mathbf a)$ and $[\mathbf D \mathbf f (\mathbf a)] \mathbf h$. Rephrasing my question: why must we use the $\mathbf h$ in $[\mathbf D \mathbf f (\mathbf a)] \mathbf h$ and not write, say $[\mathbf D \mathbf f (\mathbf a)] \color{red}{\mathbf j}$? Why does $\lim_{\mathbf h \to \mathbf 0} \frac{\mathbf r (\mathbf h)}{\lvert \mathbf h \rvert} = \mathbf 0$ require us using $\mathbf h$ instead of some other $\color{red}{\mathbf j}$?

Comment: I dont follow what you mean. You cannot change things randomly in a formula, as in the example above with $2+2=4$. Why you think that you can change $[Df(a)]\bf h$ by $[Df(a)]\bf j$? You have two identities: $\lim_{|\mathbf h|\to 0}\frac{\bf r(\bf h)}{|\bf h|}=0$ and $\mathbf h=h\bf v$, therefore $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbf r(h\bf v)}{h|\bf v|}=0$ because the sign of $h$ doesn't change the limit behavior to zero

Comment: If you wish you can change any letter, but you can't change the relationship between what the letters means. A letter is a tag for something, but if you change some symbol by another symbol in an identity, then you need to replace all instances of the old symbol, not just someones. That is: you can change $\bf v$ by $\bf w$ as far as $\bf v=\bf w$, and you must change it in all instances, otherwise you will have two different symbols to represent the same thing, what makes a formula unreadable

Comment: @Masacroso Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. To use your example, $2 + 2 = 4$ is an *identity*, and that is obvious (and yes, I know how substitutions work). On the other hand it is *not* obvious why $\mathbf r$ is defined the way it is in equation 1.7.39. I hope you can see that my question is not about substitutions but about the *definition* of $\mathbf r$. My confusion is that it seems like I could *define* $\mathbf r$ to be different (NOT substitute $\mathbf h$ for something else!), and, in following the logic of their proof, come to an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: $r$ defines the derivative $Df(x)$, that is, $f$ is differentiable at $x$ **if and only if** there exists some linear map $A$ such that the function defined by $r(h):=f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah$ have the property that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|r(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0$. Maybe this clarifies you? Anyway you dont need to know that: with the given $r$ the statement is proved, it cannot be disproved using a different definition of $r$. But Im agree that the proof seems a bit *ad-hoc*, but this depends how the derivative is presented. In many books the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is presented using $r$